# Del key doesn't fire in WebBrowser-hosted CKEditor

Tags: javascript, vb.net, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a WebBrowser-hosted CKEditor instance, but pressing the `Del` key doesn't do anything.

I tried this to get through thre problem:

**In my WebBrowser-derived class:**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreviewKeyDown(e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Delete Then
        Document.InvokeScript("pressDelete")
    End If
End Sub
```

**In my HTML page that loads CKEditor:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pressDelete() {
        return CKEDITOR.instances.myeditor.fire('key', { keyCode: 46 });
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pressDelete() {
        return CKEDITOR.instances.myeditor.document.fire('key', { keyCode: 46 });
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pressDelete() {
        return CKEDITOR.instances.myeditor.execCommand('delete');
    }
</script>
```

The first script raised a Script Error; the other two did nothing.

The case is, the rich text editor I intend to host in my Winforms application is lame if pressing `Del` doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this in the regular Internet Explorer 11 browser?

Comment: No, because I need it to be a control I can put in a Windows Form... But I sort of made it work, tweaking Webbrowser's properties. I discovered that if I let the keyboard Shortcuts enabled, then pressing Del gors through.

Comment: Yes yes, but the reason I wanted to know was because the script error _could've_ been due to an incompatible browser rather than an actual error, seeing as the WebBrowser control by default uses the IE 7 engine. Now that you got it working that doesn't matter though. :)